# How do I make this scroll function work on jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, syntax, error-handling, scroll

I'm trying to implement this scroller function, and it should work, but when I try, it is giving me a syntax error. Can someone tell me why/how to fix it?

```
Scroller = function(element) {
  this.element = this;
  this.startTouchY = 0;
  this.animateTo(0);

  element.addEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
  element.addEventListener('touchmove', this, false);
  element.addEventListener('touchend', this, false);
}
```

I'm sure I have to change `Scroller = function(element)`, but I don't know to what.

Comment: Try replacing `‘’` with normal single quotes `''`

Comment: try adding `var` in front of `Scroller`

Comment: @NifftyDude The error is on the first line..... and I did that... just forgot to add that change from the original code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
element.addEventListener(‘touchstart’, this, false);
element.addEventListener(‘touchmove’, this, false);
element.addEventListener(‘touchend’, this, false);
```

Should be this:

```
element.addEventListener('touchstart', this, false);
element.addEventListener('touchmove', this, false);
element.addEventListener('touchend', this, false);
```

The difference is I replaced the styled quotes with normal single quotes. Did you program this in Word or something?!

You should also change this:

```
var Scroller = function() {
```

To this:

```
function Scroller() {
```

Comment: acki, sorry, the original code was like that, but yes, I changed it in what I'm using! :(

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help, if I did at all. :p

Comment: Hey, I saw that uyou published something for iPhone, so I'm wondering if you know anything about making parallax work on that? I know it works on iOS5.....

Comment: @Nata2haMayan2: That's a pretty involved question. If you want a good, solid answer, I'd recommend asking a whole new question about it; you should get some solid responses. All I can say is: It depends on what framework you're using to write your app.